# EditTexts stop bottom sheet from collapsing

Tags: android, android-layout, bottom-sheet

In my app, I have several EditText views and a bottom sheet placed within a CoordinatorLayout. I can swipe up to expand the bottom sheet, but I can't swipe down to collapse it.

[image] [image]

I know it has something to do with the EditTexts because it works with TextViews in place of the EditTexts. I also noticed that if I tap somewhere on the bottom sheet where there is an EditText behind it, the keyboard pops up. I'm curious as to why the EditTexts are causing this behavior, but I'd really like to know if there is a way to fix this so that the bottom sheet can collapse if the user swipes down on it. Here's the xml file of the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/exercise_table"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:visibility="visible">
    <TableRow
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Row 1"/>

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:padding="5dp">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Row 2"/>

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:padding="5dp">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Row 3"/>

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:padding="5dp">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Row 4"/>

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="55dp">

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: post bottom_sheet_behavior

Comment: @GiddyNaya I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: what is the content of "@string/bottom_sheet_behavior" you specified for your NestedScrollView

Comment: I believe it's "com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"

Comment: A `NestedScrollView` is never a good idea for a Bottom sheet because it handles a lot of swipe gestures alreay. Use a `LinearLayout` or a `RelativeLayout` and then chuck in a `NestedScrollView` inside if you really need it

Comment: @Leo changing it to a LinearLayout did the trick! Thank you so so so much.

Comment: I can swipe down on the bottom sheet now and it will collapse. However, the keyboard still pops up when I tap on the bottom sheet if there is an EditText hidden behind it. I might post that as a separate question if I cannot figure out how to fix that.